# symfony1.4 build schema is not working

Tags: schema, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a symfony 1.4.x project  , orm propel , when i am generating a schema it display the error "You must be in a symfony project directory" , i am using windows xammp server , what can i do to generate schema model in this project , in folder structure is slightly changed from default project but its working , i need to add a new table how can i generate  schema model .is any another method to generate schema model in symfony 1.4.x. i cant find the solution.

i am not created this project , it is a existing project nee to add some fetures

all symfony command is not working inside the project , it says the same error "you must be in a symfony project". what error i made please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems as if the "slightly changed folder structure" is the problem.
Or your project settings.
Is the project itself running (in browser)?

Comment: its running in browser but web folder is not exist

Comment: all symfony command is not working inside the project , it says the same error "you must be in a symfony project". what error i made please help me

Comment: A bit more information is needed. Can you provide folder structure and the exact command you are running in the path you are running it in?

Comment: i am not generating this project , its already generated i need o do some modifications here .

Comment: Folder structure :  clientes(main directory)  : api,apps,cache,config,images,img ,js,lib,log,php-mailer ,plugin,sf,spryassesets,tema1,uploads,userfiles

Comment: command i am running :symfony cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are missing the project file itself. In your project root, a SYMFONY file should exist. The command line tool checks for this.

If you google a bit for your error message you will find several references on this.